# How do you get rownumbers for a xaml ListView in a WP 8.1 App?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1

Why are my row number snot showing? If I use this in a WP SilverLight app and a ListBox it works perfect. But with a ListView it doesn't.

Here is my code:

```
 public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var dependencyObject = value as DependencyObject;
        var item = FindFirstParentOfType<ListView>(dependencyObject);

        if (item == null)
            return null;

        var listView = (ListView)ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(item);
        if (listView == null)
            return null;

        return listView.IndexFromContainer(item) + 1;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private static T FindFirstParentOfType<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
        where T : DependencyObject
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (dependencyObject == null)
                return null;

            var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);

            var findFirstParentOfType = (parent as T);

            if (findFirstParentOfType != null)
                return findFirstParentOfType;

            dependencyObject = parent;
        }
    }
```

And on the xaml page in the ListView I do this:

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ObjectsList}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                        Converter={StaticResource ListViewItemIndexConverter}, Mode=OneTime}"
                                               Foreground="White" 
                                               FontSize="40" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />

                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

Any idea of what I forgot or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Convert method is wrong.

Where you look for `FindFirstParentOfType<ListView>`, it should be `FindFirstParentOfType<ListViewItem>`.

The method should then be like this:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
    var dependencyObject = value as DependencyObject;
    var item = FindFirstParentOfType<ListViewItem>(dependencyObject);

    if (item == null)
        return null;

    var listView = (ListView)ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(item);
    if (listView == null)
        return null;

    return listView.IndexFromContainer(item) + 1;
}
```